# Yii2 - How to hide block with dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html, css, yii2

I am trying to hide and show div in my Yii2 project using Dropdownlist change event, i have tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work for me. When I click on study_centre_id Dropdownlist onchange event, it does nothing. I will appreciate if anyone could point at where i am making mistakes. Thanks in advance.

[image: Dropdownlist]

**Controller**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Programme();       
    $model->scenario = 'import-programme';

    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**View**

```html
<div class="box-info box box-solid view-item col-xs-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
 <div class="box-header with-border">
  <h3 class="box-title"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Select File'); ?></h3>
 </div><!--./box-header-->
<div id="showProgramImport" style="display:none">        
 <div class="box-body">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'importFile')->fileInput(['title' => Yii::t('app', 'Browse Excel File')])->label(false) ?>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="callout callout-info">
     <h4><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'You must have to follow the following instruction at the time of importing data'); ?></h4>
     <ol>
      <li><b><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'The field with red color are the required field cannot be blank.'); ?></b></li>
      <li><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'The file must be CSV format.'); ?></li>
     </ol>
     <h5><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Download the sample format of Excel sheet.'); ?> <b><?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Download'), ['download-file', 'id' => 'SSF']) ?></b></h5>
    </div><!--./callout-->
   </div><!--./col-->
  </div><!--./row-->
 </div><!--./box-body-->
 <div class="box-footer">
  <?= Html::submitButton('<i class="fa fa-upload"></i>'.Yii::t('app', ' Import'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
 </div>
</div>     
<div id="showProgram" style="display:block">        
 <div class="box-body">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="callout callout-danger">
     <h4><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'You Need to Select a Study Centre.'); ?></h4>
    </div><!--./callout-->
   </div><!--./col-->
  </div><!--./row-->
 </div><!--./box-body-->

</div>        
</div><!--./box-->
```

```js
<script>
    
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#study_centre_id").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 1) { // It doesn't work over here.
                $("#showProgramImport").show();
                $("#showProgram").hide();
            } else {
                $("#showProgramImport").hide();
                $("#showProgram").show();
            }
        });
    });
});    

</script>
```

**Dropdownlist Code**

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'state_office_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\StateOffice::find()->where(['is_status' => 0])->all(),'id','state_name'),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => '--- Select State Office ---', 
                'onchange'=>'
                    $.get( "'.Url::toRoute('dependent/getstudycentre').'", { id: $(this).val() } )
                        .done(function( data ) {
                            $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'study_centre_id').'" ).html( data );
                        }
                    );' 
            ],
         //   'disabled'=>'true',
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]); ?>                            

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'study_centre_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\StudyCentre::findAll(['state_office_id' => $model->state_office_id]),'id','study_centre_name'),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => '--- Select Study Centre ---'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]); ?>             
    </div>
```

Comment: You are using the .ready() event twice here... remove either this `$(function () {` (and its closing brackets `});` or this: `$(document).ready(function() {` and its closing brackets...

Comment: I did as you instructed, but the problem is still there

Comment: what do you see in the `console` when you try to change any option from the dropdown? are there any errors there? also are you using `kartik\Select2` for the dropdown. add the code for your dropdown too in the question

Comment: There is nothing in the Console. Yes, I used kartik\Select2. Also, I have edited the post by  adding the dropdown code.   '            <?= $form->field($model, 'study_centre_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\StudyCentre::findAll(['state_office_id' => $model->state_office_id]),'id','study_centre_name'),
                'language' => 'en',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => '--- Select Study Centre ---'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]); ?> '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added id to the dropdown div as shown

```
    <div id="study_centre_id" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'study_centre_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\StudyCentre::findAll(['state_office_id' => $model->state_office_id]),'id','study_centre_name'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => '--- Select Study Centre ---'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]); ?>             
</div>
```

Then, change my script to

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#study_centre_id").change(function () {
            if ($(this).find(':selected').val() != 0) {
            $("#showProgramImport").show();
            $("#showProgram").hide();
        } else {
            $("#showProgramImport").hide();
            $("#showProgram").show();
        }
    });
});
```